# Im having Problem With my code in C Error: sementaion Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I run my code I gives me an error.   *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*

***here is my Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if(argc != 2) {

        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        printf("chould not open file");
        return 2;


    }

    unsigned char buffer[512];

    int count = 0;

    FILE *output = NULL;

    char *filename = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));

    while (fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(char), file)) {

    if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {

            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count);

             output = fopen(filename, "w");

             count++;
    }
    if(output == NULL) {
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, output);
    }

    }

    free(filename);
    fclose(output);
    fclose(file);

}
```

Comment: That allocation doesn't look big enough.

Comment: Comparing `buffer[1]` with `0xd8` on the first iteration of your loop is a bug - because you haven't explicitly initialized buffer with anything yet.  The contents could be 0xd8. Or it could be something else.  Ditto for buffer[2] and buffer[3] comparisons.

Comment: You only init 1st char of buffer at each iteration. You may think to start by reading the first 3 chars before the loop and then read the next buffer char and update pointer at end of loop. Seems you missed the homework : I have already see that test on some other topic in SO.